# Error while deploying scheduler app on railway.app

Tags: go, deployment, scheduler, prisma

I'm new to railway deployment https://railway.app/ and I came across https://github.com/operandinc/scheduler which can be used for cron jobs. I tried to deploy this on my railway account but it gives the following error: [Railway Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UPba.png). How can I resolve this?. I'm not familiar with Go language. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that github repo seems to be an incomplete fork of the original project. By saying "incomplete" I mean, the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files have several missing dependencies required to build this Go project.

Please use this one to create your Railway deployment: https://github.com/morgangallant/scheduler

Just click the "Deploy on Railway" button.

Comment: I did deploy the mentioned repository, still gives the same error.